# Remix with TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce, remix.run

Maybe someone has an example of managing to get tinymc working in Remix?
I tried multiple solutions, probably just missing something, it never loads styles for me.

I'm looking for a self-hosted solution. Tried doing it in client-side, but it never loads properly any styles or JS.